# Windows MFC macros

Tags: c++, vba, mfc

I'm trying to learn the MFC to code for Windows and I've come across things like the ID_FILE_EDIT macros that are defined as being unicode values I think. I understand, I think, that the macros specify the item in the menu pulldowns. Question is, how do I define my own and where do I put them. I'm trying to get custom menus and custom menu buttons to stem from the MFC. Like I want under file 'new, open existing doc and stuff like that'. I've got VS2013 pro and all the headers I could ever want. Second question is where do I start with the MFC. Should I start by practicing making windows then pulldowns and then... something else? I know where the documentation is at and I understand where the class references are. Really just confused on using it to make my own stuff.

Answer (score 1):

`ID_FILE_EDIT` (and other defines, like `ID_FILE_NEW`, `ID_FILE_OPEN`, etc.) are macros to specify a name for an unique resource identifier that is used to identify a menu command and/or toolbar item. They are typically defined in a header file named `resource.h`.

Microsoft has released a numbering and naming convention as a Technical Note (TN), because the names and values ​​represented by these macros must follow a certain pattern: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2zechd4.aspx

Under normal circumstances you can use Visual-Studio's built-in resource editor to create dialogues, menus, buttons, and all the other UI stuff. These editors also assign automatically unique ID's for any resource and generate the macros.

Your second question can not be answered easily. MFC applications are a wide field, ranging from simple, dialogue-based programs to sophisticated Model-View-Controller-based applications. If you just want to play around with MFC to familiarize yourself with the basic concepts of this framework, I recommend to start with a dialogue-based app.

Regards,
Stephan

Answer (score 0):

In VC++ 6.0, Insert menu - Resource - Menu. Is how you add/edit a menu.

Where is the formatting bar gone on answers.

Answer (score 0):

To learn MFC basics, manually build up the Scribble example application (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92y4h944%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) with which whole generations of MFC programmers made their first contacts with MFC. Don't just read it, start with an empty application and gradually add the stuff as in the tutorials. It'll show you a lot. If you don't know the win32 api yet though, you may want to start with reading the Petzold from front to back. Good luck, remember that these are libaries and API's from a time when it wasn't considered unreasonable to spend 3 months full time to learn something.